# useEffect trigger when a prop changes cannot be tested

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a react component using jest and enzyme.
There is a **useEffect** trigger when **a prop changes** and I am unable to test it properly.
The assertion fails due to undefined value.

This is my simplified component

```
export function SongDataModal(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.songData.songName ?? false) {
            setName(props.songData.songName);
        }
    }, [props.songData.songName]);

    return (
        <Input
            type="search"
            id="song-name-input"
            disabled={true}
            value={name}
        />
    );
}

SongDataModal.propTypes = {
    songData: PropTypes.object,
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    songData: state.songDataReducer
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
//removed the actions since they are not related
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SongDataModal);
```

And this is my test file

```
describe('SongDataModal', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const songData = { songName: 'Avicii - Levels' };

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(
      <SongDataModal
       songData={songData}
      />
    );
  });

  it('shows the song name on initial loading', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('#song-name-input').prop('value')).toBe('Avicii - Levels');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is probably because your component won't actually render the song name until it re-renders (useEffect needs to trigger on the first render, then on the second render the state value will be set). You need to use an async utility in your test to wait for the value to be visible -- in Testing Library, it's something like waitFor: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Comment: @NateNorris And also when I pass props for the shallow render like above, and try to log the wrapper using console.log(wrapper.debug()), all the fields where props are used are marked as undefined.
Is there something wrong with the way I pass the props?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`act()`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) method from RTL. I generally use it to test any conditional function calls that may happen from inside a `useEffect` hook. I use the `render` method for my purpose like this:

```
await act(() =>render(<Component/>))
```

After this, you could use async-await to `waitFor` the value to change or for a function inside the `useEffect` hook to be called. Hope that helps.
Additionaly, you could check [this](https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md) out for more insight.

Comment: Using act() is indeed the way to make sure all state changes have taken place. Act i not async by default though, so the await here won't do anything. You can make act async: `await act(async () => await somethingAync()). Render is also not async though, and has act build into it. So adding act in this way shouldn't have any effect.